# File downloaded using System.Net.FtpClient has different size than the source file

Tags: c#, download, ftp, ftp-client, filezilla

Using System.Net.FtpClient (which is a library, not a native .NET component).

I am trying to download files to local hard drive (in development environment, both the FTP server and destination local folder are on the same physical drive with different path).

I have this code.

```
using (Stream inputStream = ftpClient.OpenRead(item.FullName, FtpDataType.Binary, 15))
using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(localFilePath))
{
    try
    {
        //inputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        inputStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

**Problem:** Downloaded files are not the same size as original files.

Note that I have tried with example line `//inputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` commented because it threw exception

> "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."

And I didn't find a solution for it. Maybe this is part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the restart position to 15 (the third argument to `OpenRead` method).

So the response obviously lacks the first 15 bytes of the remote file.

---

Regarding your other question about `.Seek`:

It is irrelevant to the problem. The `FtpDataStream` (returned by `.OpenRead`) does not implement the `.Seek` method:

```
public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) {
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So I just remove the "15" and it looks fine.